# Embed Bootstrap 3 navbar in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, navbar

In bootstrap I want to create a page header which consists of a static header, a navbar in a second row and a profile picture to the right, like this:

[image]

The profile picture should be of fixed size, the title and nav bars should have the same size each and should fill the screen width.

Problem is, I got no clue how to achieve this in css, especially sind it needs to embed a bootstrap navbar. My only idea would be an old-fashioned 2x2 table where the picture spans two rows, but tables are not meant for layout problems, so sure there must be some better way in css?

Comment: what version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I use Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To show full effect Watch full-screen view.**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; border-bottom: none; border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7; width: 91.5%">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                       
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>

                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-top: 50px; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; border-top: none">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                       <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                            aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                       </div>

                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li >
                                    <a href="#">Link
                                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Action</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Action</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div style="background-color: #f0f0f0; margin-left: -30px; padding-left: 10px; position: fixed">
        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dragon/512/User.png" alt="" class="" style="width:100px;  margin-left: 10px ">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/.row-->
  <div style="height: 100vh;"></div>
</div>
<!--/.container-fluid-->
```

Comment: Nice! But somehow I see two navbars (one in the title and one below) - probably I just need to remove one from the code?

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrat 3's [media styling](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#media)

In this snippet I used only 1 embedded BS Nav and added a border color to delineate the media objects

ALSO - Bootstrap navs are responsive so when you run the snippet switch to expanded view

```css
.media {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.media, .media-body {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        <div>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="media-right">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" alt="Portrait">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        <nav>Nav</nav>
      </div>
      <div class="media-right">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" alt="Portrait">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        <nav>Nav</nav>
      </div>
      <div class="media-right">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x80" alt="Portrait">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great approach! But the dropdown is cut off inside the media heading.

Comment: seems you found a solution, but FWIW, I imagine the menu dropdowns can be addressed with some CSS.

Comment: disabling the `overflow:hidden` on the media body did the trick.